# Awaiting Multiple Axios Calls before Dispatching Action in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I have a React Redux app that needs to call multiple API endpoints using `axios`, await the results from these API calls, then dispatch an action.

**Problem:** In my current implementation below, it appears that the action is being dispatched by `redux-thunk` before the API call results are returned by `axios`.

How can we fix the problem so that we wait for all 3 results to be returned from the 3 `axios` calls, before dispatching the action?

**/src/actions/index.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
import { GET_PRICES } from './types';

export function getSpotPrice(crypto) {
    axios.get(`https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/${crypto}-USD/spot`).then( (response) => {
        return parseFloat(response.data.data.amount);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}

function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

export function getSpotPrices() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        const cryptoList = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'XRP'];
        let cryptoRates = {}

        cryptoList.forEach(async (crypto, i) => {
            await timeout(1000);        // Wait 1 sec between API calls
            cryptoRates[crypto] = await getSpotPrice(crypto);
        });

        dispatch({
            type: GET_PRICES,
            payload: cryptoRates,
        })
        console.log('cryptoRates:', cryptoRates)        // returns {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Scope/async behavior gets kind of wonky in enumerable callbacks. Try turning it into a `for..of` loop instead of `forEach`

Comment: Would parallel fetches work or do you need consecutive?

Comment: @Dom Consecutive, to avoid hammering the API endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the containing function async await all of your async calls before dispatching, like so:

```
export function getSpotPrices() {
    return async function(dispatch) {
        const cryptoList = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'XRP'];
        let cryptoRates = {}

        for(let crypto of cryptoList) {
            await timeout(1000);        // Wait 1 sec between API calls
            cryptoRates[crypto] = await getSpotPrice(crypto);
        }

        dispatch({
            type: GET_PRICES,
            payload: cryptoRates,
        });
        console.log('cryptoRates:', cryptoRates);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but a few things are off and also this slightly changes OPs intended behavior. If you want to map over the promises, you have to `return getSpotPrice(crypto)` inside `map`. You don't want to resolve the promise inside. `Promise.all` is going to call every api call in parallel, and won't wait for his 1 second interval

Comment: Right you are. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: While the above works in best-case scenarios, you should always wrap `async` calls in `try/catch` blocks. Otherwise, if the AJAX call fails, it can break the entire application. Working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-thunk-multi-api-calls-ul5h4?fontsize=14

Comment: @MattCarlotta - you don't need to wrap every `await` in `try/catch` - just the ones you actually want to catch. The OP **might be** `try/catch`ing the `dispatch(getSpotPrices())`

Comment: @MattCarlotta Thank you your codesandbox is very helpful! I am wondering why you decided to `dispatch({ type: types.CURRENCIES_FETCH });` which results in no state change in the redux store? I am guessing this is for logging/debugging purposes?

Comment: @Nyxynyx Without it, you'll display old data on remount (comment out the dispatch mentioned above, go to "Currencies", then go to "Home" then go back to "Currencies") -- it'll update the DOM with new data after 3+ seconds. Unless the user is staring intently at the data and they wait 3+ seconds, then this may confuse them into thinking it only fetches the currencies once during first mount. The above dispatch resets back to initial state on remount, causing the `<Spinner />` to show before data is fetched again -- clearer to the user that the data is being updated.

Answer (score 1):

Another way I believe you can do this is with the Promise.all method. When all the promises in an array have resolved, it's then statement is called.

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```